# Xcode reading Sharepoint list items

Tags: xcode, sharepoint

I have created code to read a sharepoint list using XCODE. The display shows the list items Titles.I wanted to know how can I display the location column data if a specific title is clicked? Do I need to make anew .xib file?
Ex(Main display):

**Title**
      Sin City
      Windy City
    
    
    Show Chicago if Windy City is clicked.
    Show Las Vega is Sin City is clicked.